# I need to integrate junit-report results back to x-ray jira based on the ticket number on jira

Tags: tags, cypress, metadata, jira, integration

I'm trying to generate a custom XML report for my cypress tests so they can map directly to a specific issue type in Xray for Jira upon import. I've read through a lot of the documentation on reporters and I've set up the configuration to generate XML files for tests/test runs so currently I can generate a combined report of my whole test suite, but when I import the file into Xray it creates new issuekeys. I already have created the test cases in Xray and I want my XML file to contain specific information on which cypress test should go to each Xray test case. Does anyone have advice or know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this on one [post on Atlassian Community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/XRay-test-execution-import-map-junit-results-to-existing-test/qaq-p/1794429).

Briefly, you need to put the following into your XRay Test Case Definition field:

```
report_testcase_classname.report_testcase_name
```

Assuming you have the following lines in your **results.xml** file:

```
  <testsuite name="Feature A" timestamp="2023-09-20T13:16:15" tests="1" time="5.201" failures="0">
    <testcase name="Feature A Should test a functionality" time="5.159" classname="Should test a functionality">
```

You need to add *Should test a functionality.Feature A Should test a functionality* in the Definition of your XRay Test Case.

To figure it out better, check the Definition of the XRay Test Cases created when you import the XML file, and whatever they display in the Definition field is what you need to have in the Test Case you want to map.